# Trocar os caracteres de lugar - C

Tags: c

Preciso escrever um programa em C que receba como parâmetro uma palavra (string) e gere uma nova string que consiste na string original com as seguintes alterações:

> ● O primeiro caractere da string deve ser colocado no fim da string;
>
> ● Deve ser adicionado o sufixo “ay” ao fim dessa string. Considere que
> a string recebida pelo programa terá, no máximo, 100 caracteres. Não
> usar nenhuma função da biblioteca `<string.h>`

Mas estou com dificuldades para trocar os caracteres de lugar.

Código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    
    char string[101];
    char letra[2];
    char comp[3]="ay";
    int count, i;
    
    printf("String:  ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    
    for(count=1; string[i]!='\0'; i++){
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que este código resolva o problema...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    char string[101];
    char letra[2];
    char comp[3]="ay";
    int count, i;

    printf("String:  ");
    scanf("%s", string);

    for(count=0; string!='\0'; i++){
        count++;
    }
    letra[0]=string[0];
    string[0]=string[count];
    string[count]=letra[0];
    string[count+1]='a';
    string[count+2]='y';
    printf("%s",string);
}
```

Se pudesse usar `<string.h>` seria mais fácil:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()

{

    char string[101], backup;

    int tamanho_str;

    printf("String:  ");
    scanf("%s", string);

    tamanho_str = strlen (string);

    backup = string[tamanho_str-1];

    string [tamanho_str-1] = string [0];

    string [0] = backup;

    strcat (string, "ay");

    printf ("\nstring final: %s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```